# Unable to fetch data from Facebook API

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created an app which take photos from Facebook. I have two questions

1. When I run my app from emulator and login with Facebook with my account I get the data, but when I run it on real device (my wife device and there is her Facebook account) the data is nil.
2. How can I get a full size photos? Here is my request

   ```
   FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/albums", parameters: ["fields":"id, name, cover_photo{picture}, photos{picture.type(large)}
   ```

But type (large) doesn't work anymore

Comment: 1) Most likely missing permissions. If you did not assign your wife's account a role in the app, then you need to submit it for review, before you can ask normal accounts for those. 2) Not sure type was ever supposed to work with normal photos, AFAIK that was for stuff like profile pictures only. Try the `photos(images)` sub-field, it should return all available image sizes.

Comment: thanks bro, the photos(images) works good, but i don't understand what need i do for first problem? If i need to send fro review where can i get url for privacy and policy and other? this is my test app

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways to check this.**

**1. You should go to developers.facebook.com and add your wife's account to Roles section.**

**2. You should check if the app is in development phase, if so then only you can use it to get data. In order to get data from all accounts you need to make it public.**

[image]

**Select the suitable permissions and submit for review after you have completed all the details.**

[image]

Comment: it was as public

Comment: In that case check if she has allowed permission to the app and her privacy settings are apt. Because since the app is public, the same code that is working for you should work for her as well.

Comment: where can i check it? I add her for tester role, but it doesn't help

Comment: Remove the app from your wife’s account under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, and try and login to the app again.